# AsyncTask for sending data to server

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am writing an `AsyncTask` that is expected to send the data to the server continuously in background. I have called it in `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`. But it is not working. The toast in `onPreExecute()` is displayed then nothing happens.

```
private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
 {
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() 
      {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // update the UI immediately after the task is executed
            super.onPreExecute();
      }

          @Override
          protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
          {
             // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/BPCLTracker/gpsdata.txt");
              int i=0;

              RandomAccessFile in = null;

              try
              {
                  in = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
              } 
              catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
              {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              //String line =null;
              while (true) 
              {
                HttpEntity entity=null;
                try 
                {
                    if (new GPSLoggerService().isInternetOn()) 
                    {
                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                            {

                                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                String url = "http://67.23.166.35:80/android/insert.php";
                                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
                                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(line);
                                se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
                                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                                entity = se;
                                request.setEntity(entity);
                                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                                entity = response.getEntity();
                                i++;
                            }
                            if((line = in.readLine()) == null && entity!=null)
                            {
                                file.delete();
                                new MyAsync().execute();
                            }


                    }// end of if
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(60000);

                    } // end of else
                }// end of try
                catch (NullPointerException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e2) 
                {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e1) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }// end of while

      }//doinbackground

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
         // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

     }//AsyncTask
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code to see where the problem lies?

Comment: are you getting any error? By the way this is not a right use case for `Asynctask` as per guidelines it should not be used for long running task.. you can use `Service` for long running task...

Comment: The `onPostExecute` method will never be called because of `while (true)`.

Comment: `while(true)` rocks !!

Comment: thank you all. I learnt some thing new from u all.

Answer (score 3):

For a question, you need to be a little more specific on what is happening. However, you don't want to do it this way. `AsyncTask` is for short lived operations/ According to the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

You have an infinite loop with `while(true)` which is rarely a good idea. I suggest you rethink how you do this. You could set up a `Timer`, `AlarmManager`, or a `Service` but I suggest you don't use `AsyncTask` for this

Comment: @user2082987 you are most welcome! You may accept if this answer helped you or let me know if you need a better understanding. Good luck!

Comment: not sure if this question is old or so.. but i'm asking any way you may get this... so what you saying here is AsyncTask isn't good for uploading such large files ..? and is the answer below is a good idea to do the uploading outside of doInBackground and return the response to pass ...... can that give a "long life" for the AsyncTask ?

Comment: @Alamri the OP is using `AsyncTask` for continuous work which is not what its meant for. You can upload large amount of files if the operation doesn't take too long. The problem is if you switch `Activities` while doing so or leaving the app. That is why other APIs such as a `Service` is better for longer operations. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can upload data continuously by using using service. I Provide the code that run in background and uplaod data on server continuously .

you just call this service :

startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class));

Also Add entry in Android Manifest File

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class BackgroundService extends IntentService
{
    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundService";
    Context mContext = null;

    final static int SERVICE_NAME = 1;
    int WORK_TYPE;

    public BackgroundService()
    {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {

        mContext = getBaseContext();
        WORK_TYPE = SETTING;
        new BackgroundTask(mContext).execute();
    }

    public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
    {
        Context mContext = null;

        public BackgroundTask(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(final String... args)
        {
            switch (WORK_TYPE)
            {
                case SETTING:
                String input = "what ever text data post on server";
                response = sendDataToServer(input);
                JsonUtils.parseServerData(response, hashMapObj);
                break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused)
        {
            switch (WORK_TYPE)
            {
                case SETTING:
                    if (!"".equalsIgnoreCase(response) && response != null)
                    {
                        DeviceUtils.deviceRegistration(hashMapObj, mContext);   
                    }
                    callService(SERVICE_NAME);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void callService(int work)
    {
        WORK_TYPE = work;
        new BackgroundTask(mContext).execute();
    }


    public String sendDataToServer(String data)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String serverUrl = "http://67.23.166.35:80/android/insert.php" ;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL();
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(6 * 10 * 1000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Process line...
                sb.append(line);
            }

            wr.close();
            rd.close();
            return sb.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Exception : ", e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much Sanjeev Badoni. I ll try this.

Comment: What is the WORKTYPE and SETTINGS

Comment: OOOh I got it. But What is activation Status here

Comment: There is no need of Activation Status so i removed it

Answer (score 0):

i noticed that your parameters in asyncTask is all void try changing the first one as a String  of course change also the parameter of do in background as a String then invoke your class to your onCreate. follow this as a reference

```
public class reqDataREST extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
            "http://icommute-ph.com/api/v1/todos/");

    try {
    // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", tstData.getText().toString()));
                postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        BasicHttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, new BasicCookieStore());

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest, httpContext);
        //int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your device has internet access and also that you have granted internet access permission in your AndroidManiest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```